# Space between two buttons on a Bootstrap form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to add some space between 2 buttons. This form is created using bootstrap. Tried a number of tricks but couldn't get what I want. The same page is accessed via mobile too.

Here is my code along with screenshot:

```
<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button"  style="border-radius: 10px;"  id="button1"   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  value="My Provider"/>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn" > &nbsp;
            <input type="button"  style="border-radius: 10px;" id="button2"   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"   value="Any Provider"/>
        </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding some padding left of the second button?

Comment: tried but that does mess
 up responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Bootstrap's `btn-block` class.

> A block level button spans the entire width of the parent element.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp

Try removing that class from each of your buttons, setting the width of the `input-group` class to 100% and adding margin after the first button.

```css
input[type=button] {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 47%;
}

.input-group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=button]:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="button" id="button1"   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  value="My Provider"/>
     <input type="button" id="button2"   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Any Provider"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add paddings to `input-group-btn` blocks.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.input-group-btn-left {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.input-group-btn-right {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn input-group-btn-left">
      <input type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="My Provider" style="border-radius: 10px;">
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn input-group-btn-right">
      <input type="button" id="button2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Any Provider" style="border-radius: 10px;">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```